# Get number of bytes emitted by stream

Tags: node.js, stream, nodejs-stream

I can find out the number of bytes emitted to data handlers using:

```
let bytesEmitted = 0;

strm.setEncoding('utf8');

strm.on('data', d => {
  bytesEmitted += Buffer.byteLength(d);
});
```

but I am looking for way to access the number of bytes emitted without having to attach my own handler.

There is a property - strm.bytesRead - but I am fearful that this doesn't represent the number of "bytes emitted" - it has to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

[This is the commit](https://github.com/JacksonTian/node/blob/9a2a4464075c98a44710dac40d326f6875c4bb38/lib/_stream_readable.js) that introduced the `bytesRead` property to `Readable` streams.

We can see on line 140 that the property is updated when a new chunk of data becomes available, and on line 148 the `data` event is emitted immediately thereafter so long as the stream remains flowing. For a stream that finishes without leaving the flowing state you can feel free to poll or otherwise access the `bytesRead` property at any point and consider it equal to the actual number of bytes emitted. However, if you pause the stream the buffered `bytesRead` may lag behind the actual bytes emitted until all available chunks are consumed.

Please be warned that this behavior isn't documented and could be subject to change at any time.

Comment: The property doesn't exist anymore (Node v16)